# Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore: Line 49 failed

Tags: centos, iptables

I'm trying to run the following line
`echo “-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT” >> /etc/sysconfig/iptables && sudo /etc/init.d/iptables restart`

But I get the following error:

`iptables: Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore: line 49 failed
                                                           [FAILED]`

This is my iptables file

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Aug 17 19:21:57 2016
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [55:3224]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [696:43973]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [696:43973]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Aug 17 19:21:57 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Aug 17 19:21:57 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:cP-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j cP-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j cP-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2083 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2079 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2077 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2095 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2096 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2082 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2080 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 26 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2086 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2087 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2078 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Aug 17 19:21:57 2016
“-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT”
“-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT”
```

I'm running centos 6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes are the problem, also there should be nothing after the final `COMMIT`

You can run `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT` then `iptables-save` to append the rule to the appropriate chain.

If you must edit the /etc/sysconfig/iptables file then do so with vim or vi and insert the rules at line 18.

If you need to add those rules to your `cP-Firewall-1-INPUT` then replace `INPUT` with `cP-Firewall-1-INPUT` so the command would be `iptables -A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT`